# Starting a thread in a c++ dll, from a C# wpf application, do I need a thread inside a thread?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading

I have a C# / WPF application that runs functions from a c++ dll, and returns data into a callback.

To avoid locking the UI, I start a thread in C# that starts a new thread in the dll.

c#

```
Thread threadZ = new Thread(StartTracking);
threadZ.IsBackground = true;
threadZ.Start();
```

c++

```
__declspec(dllexport) void StartTracking()
{

    std::thread procThread = std::thread([&]() {
        m.ttrack->Connect(callback, callbackFrames); });

    procThread.join();

}
```

This seems redundant, as I am starting a thread just to start a thread.
But if i do not start a new c# thread, the UI locks up.
If I just run the function in c++, without starting a new c++ thread, I see strange issues with my returned data, where the latency will rise and fall. In a new thread, it is stable.
For example, the latency of my callback data is 6ms when I launch the application. When the application is minimised for a period of time, or I am using another application while it is running, the latency will rise to 800ms or more.

My question is:

Do I need to run a thread-inside-a-thread like this? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: You just need a thread in C#. You only need `IsBackground = true` if you want it to be terminated when the application ends. Regarding "strange returned data" and "latency", we need more details. I can't see how a thread would make stuff better.

Comment: More information added. It seems like if I just launch a C# thread, the latency of my data callback is tied to the UI somehow. After it has been running for an hour or so, with the application minimised, the latency will rise. If I use a c++ thread as above, this does not happen.

Comment: There are two questions here. The answer to "do I need two threads" is "no, just make one in C#". The answer to the second question is "create another question with more information than the almost nothing you've provided, and we might be able to help you".

Comment: For a 6 ms callback, you should not need threading at all. That's not a time where the UI would feel unresponsive. If it deadlocks, then you should resolve that deadlock.

Answer (score -2):

About the use of threads in both C # and C ++. Keep in mind that they will be different contexts, so if the following questions have affirmative answers, continue to use them.

1 - In your WPF form, do you want to allow your user to perform other actions while the routine is not completed (responsiveness)?

2 - In the routine created in C ++, consumed by C # through the DLL, are there other activities that can be performed in parallel to the main flow?

As for the latency issue, I would advise you to change your approach a bit. Instead of instantiating new threads whenever you use your C ++ routine (new Thread(StartTracking)). Try to use [the pool of threads managed by .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool). In the past, I have seen significant performance improvements in adopting this approach.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x)=> StartTracking);
```